# Navgation Controller and UIImageView in a custom cell in UITableView

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uiimageview

In my app's navigation controller is an UITableViewContoller then a ViewController.  The user selects an item in the UITableViewContollrer, this calls the ViewController.  If the user hits the back button I need to visually show which item was selected before.  Doing this with a UIImage, basically want to hide or show it.  Problem is I cannot find a method  that will parse each cell in the UITableView and determine if the the cell was selected before when the UITable is called again.

Some background on the UITableView, it is based on an entity in core data.  The selected item is stored in a different entity in core data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly declare NSIndexPath *selectedIndexPath and creates its property. Now in tableView Delegate:

```
- (void)selectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath animated:(BOOL)animated scrollPosition:(UITableViewScrollPosition)scrollPosition
{
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}
```

You have selected IndexPath of cell in tableView. When hits back button of navigator bar, ViewControllers viewWillApper will be called

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
  [super viewWillAppear:animated];
  if(selectedIndexPath)
  {
   //if you have custom cell then you will get custom cell which was selected just use custom cell object in place of UITableViewCell

   UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*)[YourtableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:selectedIndexPath];

   //You have cell reference which was selected when one view controller was pushed in navigation controller.
   // you can change image or label text which are present in your cell
   // cell.ImageView or cell.labelText anything
  }
}
```

Hope it is useful.

Comment: I must be doing something wrong, as I step through the viewWillAppear it never went through the if statement.